# How to communicate between JS and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, discord

I have made a Discord bot in which I wanted to add the Oxford Dictionary API.
So,if you give input "!find ***word-to-search***" the bot will return the meaning of the word.

I have done almost everything, I have a python script that takes a string input and returns the meaning of it.
And, I have a JS file that takes user input and then responds accordingly.

What I want to do is, take user input in JS file, send it to the python file, which returns the meaning of the word.

I am using **`Heroku`** to host by bot

**I need your help, to let me know how to send the input string from `bot.js` to `trying.py` and then return an array of string from `trying.py` to `bot.js`**

The code of both the files is :

**`trying.py`**

```
import requests
import json


app_id = 'my-app-id'
app_key = 'my-app-key'

language = 'en-gb'
word_id = 'Hello'
fields = 'definitions'
strictMatch = 'false'

url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/' + language + '/' + word_id.lower() + '?fields=' + fields + '&strictMatch=' + strictMatch;

r = requests.get(url, headers = {'app_id': app_id, 'app_key': app_key})

theListOfMeanings = r.json()

if 'error' in theListOfMeanings:
    print("Sorry, I couldn't find ",word_id," in the dictionary\nPlease check the spelling")
else:
    counter=1
    print("The different meanings of",word_id," are -")
    for j in theListOfMeanings['results']:
        for x in j['lexicalEntries']:       
            for i in (x['entries'][0]['senses']):
                print(counter,". "," ".join(i['definitions']))
                counter+=1
```

**Bot.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require('./auth.json') //TEMPORARY


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send("Welcome"); 
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  theMessage = msg.content
  if (msg.content === '!hello') {
    msg.reply('Hii ! :grin:');
  }      
  else if (theMessage.slice(0, 5) === '!find'){
    msg.reply('Hi, my name is Norm :neutral_face:')    
    //theMessage.pop(0)
    theMessage = theMessage.substring(5);    
    msg.reply(theMessage);

  }
});
client.login(auth.token);
```

I agree that recoding the python script in JS  will be a good idea.
But, the problem is, the node.js code available at [Oxford](https://developer.oxforddictionaries.com/documentation#!/Entries/get_entries_source_lang_word_id) returns an output, that I don't know how to manage.
The node.js code (replacement for trying.py) is available in the above link, it's output for me is this : 
[image: chaotic output]

If someone can tell me how I can use the returned JS code, I'll be very grateful.

OXFORD API CODE (Node.js(replacement of trying.py))

```
const http = require("https");

const app_id = "my_app_id"; // insert your APP Id
const app_key = "my_app_key"; // insert your APP Key
const wordId = "ace";
const fields = "pronunciations";
const strictMatch = "false";

const options = {
  host: 'od-api.oxforddictionaries.com',
  port: '443',
  path: '/api/v2/entries/en-gb/' + wordId + '?fields=' + fields + '&strictMatch=' + strictMatch,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    'app_id': app_id,
    'app_key': app_key
  }
};

http.get(options, (resp) => {
    let body = '';
    resp.on('data', (d) => {
        body += d;
    });
    resp.on('end', () => {
        let parsed = JSON.stringify(body);

        console.log(parsed);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not recode the small request of the python file in JavaScript ? It would be quite easy, just make use of the `node-fetch` npm module.

Comment: I second @Tenclea's idea. It's easier to code everything in one language than having two programs communicate with each other. Fetching the data using JS should be straightforward.

Comment: @Tenclea, I have just edited the question, please take a look  ;)

Comment: @RohitGarg once you made the request and converted it to json, try to reach the response.body, what you're searching should be there

Comment: @Tenclea, I found the response body.
I have also attached the screenshot of it.
I am unable to understand how to get information out of the response.

I did it easily in python by using the json library, how can I do it in JS ?

Comment: @RohitGarg I do not really know how this API reponses look like, but I suppose the response you got should be very similar to the one you had in Python, right ?

Comment: @RohitGarg I just look carefully at your screenshot, and it seems all the data you requested is here. Now you can use your json like a Python dictionary variable

Comment: Yes, all the information I need is present in the response.
The very problem is, I don't know how to access that response.
I want to scrap the required values.

I used 3 nested loops in python to use the response.
How to do the same thing in JS  ?

Comment: @RohitGarg well, it should work the same way. make a first `for (let j of json.result) { ...` then another with the lexical entries, etc.. I hope you understand me ^^'

Comment: @Tenclea , sorry I am troubling you a lot.
Can you please point out which exact variable in the code is storing the response ? 
I tried printing the body variable, but it's  working as a string instead of a dictionary/array.

Comment: @RohitGarg have you tried to run a `JSON.parse(yourVariable)` on the response ?

Comment: @Tenclea It appears to be working !!!
The response looks same as  the python one. Still a problem :/
I cannot access the variable, typing `console.log(mainer["id"]);` returns `undefined`.

`mainer` is the variable which stores the parsed value.

Comment: @RohitGarg Then I'd suggest you to log the mainer value to see what is wrong

Comment: @Tenclea I don't know how to thank you.
It worked!
I will now work on the complete project. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved in the comments, by recoding the program in JS using the `node-fetch` npm module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working Javascript Snippet that fetches the definitions for you using node-fetch.

Outputs

```
hello
1. [interjection] used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation
1. [noun] an utterance of ‘hello’; a greeting
1. [verb] say or shout ‘hello’
world
1. [noun] the earth, together with all of its countries and peoples
2. [noun] a particular region or group of countries
3. [noun] human and social interaction
```

---

```
const fetch = typeof window !== 'undefined'?window.fetch:require("node-fetch")

const app_id = "f84663ce"; // insert your APP Id
const app_key = "9d0cc4ee0694e65386b9bfd69cba3aba"; // insert your APP Key
const fields = "definitions";
const strictMatch = "false";

async function lookupDefs (wordId = 'ace') {
  const url = 'https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com/api/v2/entries/en-gb/' + wordId + '?fields=' + fields + '&strictMatch=' + strictMatch;
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      'app_id': app_id,
      'app_key': app_key
    }
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  return response.json();
}

(async () => {
    for (const word of ['hello', 'world']) {

      const res = await lookupDefs(word);
      console.log (word);
      for (const result of res.results) {
        for (const entry of result.lexicalEntries) {
          for (let i=0; i<entry.entries[0].senses.length; i++) {
          const sense = entry.entries[0].senses[i];
          const cat = entry.lexicalCategory.id;
          console.log(`${i+1}. [${cat}] ${sense.definitions.join(', ')}`);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can go, but I will suggest you only flask since I believe it will require minimal amount of efforts for you to start.

You need to create Flask application, place your javascript code as static assets which talks to flask view. The flask view internally execute logic you wrote in python script and return json response to the javascript code, take a look on [Flask quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/) and [Flask by Example – Project Setup](https://realpython.com/flask-by-example-part-1-project-setup/) as your starting point.

When you complete the application on local machine here is guides on [deploying python application on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) and [Deploy Python Flask App on Heroku](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deploy-python-flask-app-on-heroku/)
.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your initial question, here is how you could let the two communicate. This assumes that both the JavaScript script and Python script are located on the same machine and can communicate through the stdin/stdout channels.

```py
# script.py
import sys

word = sys.stdin.read().strip()
print('definition of ' + word)
```

```js
// script.js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// assuming script.py is in the same folder
const python = spawn('python', ['script.py']);

python.stdout.on('data', data => {
  const definition = data.toString().trim();
  console.log(definition);
});

const userInput = 'Foo';
python.stdin.end(userInput);
```

When you run:

```bash
node script.js
```

It will print:

```
definition of Foo
```